# Converting collection permalinks Jekyll 2 -> 3

Tags: collections, jekyll, permalinks

I have several collections where Jekyll generates GeoJSON from the source. With 2.4, I gave each file in the collection a random extension, such as abc.xx, with the following example definition in _config.yml:

```
features:
  output: true
  permalink: /features/:path.geojson
```

This would take abc.xx and put the output in /features/abc.geojson

This no longer works in Jekyll 3. It now creates /features/abc.geojson.xx which isn't correct, and I cannot work out how to retain the previous behaviour. If I leave out the extension, e.g. abc, the file isn't output. If I call it e.g. 'abc.' then I get a syntax error. I tried with ':name' instead of ':path' but that didn't work either. I cannot call the source abc.geojson because the source isn't GeoJSON and Github will try and render the source if it's called .geojson. Apart from this, I don't care what the source is called so long as it creates abc.geojson.

Anyone?

Later: I have 2 GeoJSON files that are not part of a collection. The source for these was called xxx.geo with a permalink of `/xxx.geojson` in the front matter. I renamed these to just 'xxx' without an extension and a file 'xxx.geojson' is correctly generated. So it's looking increasingly like, apart from the change in behaviour from version 2, there is a bug in the processing of collections: collection items without an extension are not being output.

Comment: https://github.com/pilgrimdb/pilgrimdb.github.io simp and unmapped are the 2 files that are now correctly output. Example collection is _routefc

Comment: This seems to be a bug.

Comment: ok, thanks. Will you raise this on the jekyll repo, or should I?

Comment: You do. Try to reproduce this on a minimal jekyll site and open a bug explaining what was the result under Jekyll 2 and what append with jekyll 3.